# Spotify API Drag & Drop playlists

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, spotify

I want to create a drag and droppable playlist using the Spotify API.

```
var tracks = models.library.tracks;
var playlist = new models.Playlist();

// loop through all tracks and add them to the playlist
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var track = models.Track.fromURI(tracks[i].data.uri);
  playlist.add(track);
}

// add playlist to view
var playlistView = new views.List(playlist);
$('#playlist').html(playlistView.node);
```

**How would I make this playlist enabled for dragging and dropping the tracks?**
Is this already built in to the Spotify API (but not documented yet)?
I tried to implement it myself using jQuery UIs sortable function.

```
$('#playlist').sortable();
```

However, Spotify playlists aren't simple `ul` and `li` child elements, so this didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't that the playlist isn't displayed using **ul** and **li** elements. The jQuery UI sortable function actually works fine with a **div** tag containing **a** tags, particularly if (as is the case with Spotify) the **a** tags have their **display** style set to **table**. You simply need to tell the function what child items are sortable by using something like:

```
$('#playlist').sortable({ items: 'a.sp-item' });
```

That tells it that links with the class of **sp-item** are sortable.

However, it still doesn't quite work when doing that as the items snap back to the original positions. This is because each row in the playlist is set to use absolute positioning and uses the -webkit-transform CSS property to position it at the correct Y-coordinates. This results in the "snap-back" experienced.

I have found a workaround for this, although it is rather a hack. Simply add the following code before you set the list to sortable:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#playlist > div > div a.sp-item').attr("style","").css("position","relative");
}, 100);
```

This basically removes the "-webkit-transform" style from all the links in the playlist and changes them to use relative positioning (the timeout is because the list doesn't appear to be fully constructed immediately after creating it). Strangely this doesn't seem to affect the display of the playlist at all, so it makes me wonder why it was done like this...

Answer (score 0):

I did this exact thing a few days ago, for the site below. Scroll down, click the tabs, add a few tracks to build up a list and drag and drop about.

http://cultureclash.redbull.co.uk/getonstage/

The pertinent code is at http://cultureclash.redbull.co.uk/getonstage/js/getonstage-ui.js starting at line 106. The playlist itself is stored somewhere else as an array of tracks encoded just as Spotify has them.

When the user adds a track, I grab that array and put it through a template to generate the DOM for the sortable, then I give `data-index` attributes to each `li` to keep track of which index of the original array they represent. When the `sortstop` event fires, I go through the `ul`, take note of the new order, and shift the array to match.

Have a deeper look at that file and play about with the app using a DOM inspector to work out the finer details.